# How to restrict Meteor.publish() based on a url param?

Tags: node.js, meteor

I am new to Meteor and to server-side Javascript. I've been stuck on a seemingly trivial problem: I want to restrict data published by the server according the a path or query string. For example when accessing foo.com/cars/123 I would like the 'cars' collection to only contain the record of car '123'.

I can't find the way to access complete URL in the server-side code where I am calling Meteor.publish().

I first tried to look for some variable that would contain the complete URL and then parse it. I could only find Meteor.absoluteUrl(), which only contains the protocol, host and the port, but the path and query string are stripped.

I tried creating routes that can capture the url params, but when I place Meteor.publish inside the route function no data gets published. It kind of works when I capture the param value in a router, save it as global and then use it when publishing:

```
// main.js

Meteor.startup(() => {
  WebApp.connectHandlers.use("/", function(req, res, next) {
    const params = require('url').parse(req.url, true).query;
    global.carId = params['carId'];

    next();
  });

});

// cars.js

export default CarData = new Mongo.Collection('car-data');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('carData', function tasksPublication() {
        return CarData.find({id: global.carId || 'demo'});
    });
}
```

However it would not work with parallel requests, I'd need to use a request-scoped variable instead, which I cannot figure out neither.

Finally I considered replacing the global variable by a global map indexed by Meteor.connection._lastSessionId, but it does not feel like a robust solution..

I will be grateful for your hints!

**EDIT: The solution I found**

```
// cars.js

export default CarData = new Mongo.Collection('car-data');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('carData', carId) => {
        return CarData.find({id: carId});
    });
}

// frontend

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const flowId = urlParams.get("carId");
Meteor.subscribe('carData', carId);
```

Comment: To subscribe to data you need to call `Meteor.subscribe` on the client. So based on different routes you can create different publications like `carData.url1` and `carData.url2` and you subscribe to the one, that is mapped for your url. This is a sole client side decision **which** publication to subscribe to. The decision, whether the client is allowed to receive data from publications should not be decided by url but the roles the current client user owns (see `alanning:roles` package).

Comment: thanks for a quick reply!  Should I really create a separate publication for each car? Or could I possibly publish the whole collection and  ```Meteor.subscribe```  would be smart enough to only fetch the needed data over the network?

Comment: Both. Meteor.publish defines what data is sent to whom. This includes which documents (query), which order (sort), how many (limit), all fields or only a subset (fields). Meteor.subscribe is only there to invoke (with or without arguments) the data to be received.